# Euclidian distance between posts based on tags

Tags: python, similarity, euclidean-distance

I am playing with the euclidian distance example from programming collective intelligence book,

```
# Returns a distance-based similarity score for person1 and person2 
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2): 
  # Get the list of shared_items 
  si={} 
  for item in prefs[person1]: 
    if item in prefs[person2]: 
       si[item]=1 
  # if they have no ratings in common, return 0 
  if len(si)==0: return 0 
  # Add up the squares of all the differences 
  sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) 
                      for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
```

this is the original code for ranking movie critics, i am trying to modify this to find similar posts, based on tags i build a map such as,

```
url1 - > tag1 tag2
url2 - > tag1 tag3
```

but if apply this to the function,

```
pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
```

this becomes 0 cause tags don't have weight same tags has ranking 1. I modified the code to manually create a difference to test,

```
pow(prefs[1,2)
```

then i got a lot of 0.5 similarity, but similarity of the same post to it self is dropped down to 0.3. I can't think of a way to apply euclidian distance to my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first off, your code looks incomplete: I see only one return from your function. I think you mean something like this:

```
def sim_distance(prefs, person1, person2): 
  # Get the list of shared_items
  p1, p2 = prefs[person1], prefs[person2]
  si = set(p1).intersection(set(p2))

  # Add up the squares of all the differences 
  matches = (p1[item] - p2[item] for item in si)
  return sum(a * a for a in matches)
```

Next, your post needs a bit of editing for clarity. I don't know what this means: "this becomes 0 cause tags don't have weight same tags has ranking 1."

Lastly, it would help if you provided sample data for `prefs[person1]` and `prefs[person2]`. Then you could tell what you are getting and what you expect to get.

Edit: based on my comment below, I would use code like this:

```
def sim_distance(prefs, person1, person2):
    p1, p2 = prefs[person1], prefs[person2]
    s, t = set(p1), set(p2)
    return len(s.intersection(t)) / len(s.union(t))
```

Comment: what i menat is assuming 2 posts share the tag (tag1) as the only similar tag. then  (p1[item] - p2[item] for item in si) every item in si will be 0 no? cause tags are either 0 or 1 in the shared case they are all 1 then 1 - 1 will be 0.

Comment: The Euclidean distance code is intended to calculate similarity between two things that share a numerical measure. You are applying this to something that has no numerical measure. I would use a variation on Aziz's idea: I'd compare the count of identical elements to count of unique elements in both sets.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, tags don't have weights and can't be represented by numerical values. So you can't define a distance between two tags.

If you want to find the similarity between two posts using their tags, I would suggest that you use the ratio of similar tag. For example, if you have

```
url1 -> tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4
url2 -> tag1 tag4 tag5 tag6
```

then you have 2 similar tags, representing `2 (similar tags) / 4 (total tags) = 0.5`. I think this would represent a good measurement for similarity, as long as you have more than 2 tags per post.